# Remove Emacs highlighting

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I use the emacs command 'highlight-compare-buffers' to see the changes between two files.  But I don't know how to turn the highlighting off.  It seems like it should be really easy, but I can't seem to figure out how even with lots of googling and searching the emacs help files.

Comment: @Alex Assuming you're not trolling, click on the `emacs` tag (the button just above your comment), and then click on the `about the emacs tag`, and you'll learn about Emacs.  The same process works for any tag.  This is the link you'll end up at: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/emacs/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

**C-u -1 M-x highlight-compare-buffers**

> global-highlight-changes is an
>   interactive autoloaded Lisp function
>   in `hilit-chg'.
>
> (global-highlight-changes &optional
>   arg)
>
> Turn on or off global Highlight
>   Changes mode.
>
> When called interactively:
>
> - if no prefix, toggle global Highlight Changes mode on or off
> - if called with a positive prefix (or just C-u) turn it on in active mode
> - if called with a zero prefix turn it on in passive mode
> - if called with a negative prefix turn it off

Answer (score 1):

I don't have emacs installed on this box, so this is untested, but `highlight-changes-toggle-visibility` might work.